# Carathéodory's theorem and ${\displaystyle \alpha :=\min _{1\leq j\leq k}\left\{{\tfrac {\lambda _{j}}{\mu _{j}}}:\mu _{j}>0\right\}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

[Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull))  states that

> Assume $x \in \mathbb R^d$ and $x \in \text{CH}(P)$, then $X$ can be written as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points in $P$.

The proof is given by:

Let $x$ be a point in the convex hull of $P$, then $x$ is a convex combination of finite points in $P$:
$$x=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_j x_j$$

Where every $x_j$ is in $P$,every $λ_j$ is (w.l.o.g.) positive, and ${\displaystyle \sum _{j=1}^{k}\lambda _{j}=1}$
Suppose $k > d + 1$ (otherwise, there is nothing to prove).

**I think if $k \le d+1$, then $x$ is already written as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points in $P$ and that's why if the case happens, then there is nothing to prove**

Then, the vectors $x_2 − x_1, ..., x_k − x_1$ are linearly dependent,

**I think the linear independence of these vectors is because they belong to $\mathbb R^d$, so if we choose $m$  of them with $m > d$, then they cannot be linearly independent**

So there are real scalars $μ_2, ..., μ_k$, not all zero, such that

$${\displaystyle \sum _{j=2}^{k}\mu _{j}(\mathbf {x} _{j}-\mathbf {x} _{1})=\mathbf {0} .}$$

If $μ_1$ is defined as

$${\displaystyle \mu _{1}:=-\sum _{j=2}^{k}\mu _{j}}$$
then

$${\displaystyle \sum _{j=1}^{k}\mu _{j}\mathbf {x} _{j}=\mathbf {0} }\;;\,\;\;
{\displaystyle \sum _{j=1}^{k}\mu _{j}=0}$$
and not all of the $μ_j$ are equal to zero. Therefore, at least one $μ_j > 0$ Then,
$$\mathbf{x} = \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j \mathbf{x}_j-\alpha\sum_{j=1}^k \mu_j \mathbf{x}_j = \sum_{j=1}^k (\lambda_j-\alpha\mu_j) \mathbf{x}_j$$
for any real $α$. In particular, the equality will hold if $α$ is defined as

$${\displaystyle \alpha :=\min _{1\leq j\leq k}\left\{{\tfrac {\lambda _{j}}{\mu _{j}}}:\mu _{j}>0\right\}={\tfrac {\lambda _{i}}{\mu _{i}}}.} $$

**This is where I don't understand, all we know is that some of $\mu_j$'s are not zero, so some of them can be zero or negative, so based on what condition we define such $\alpha$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all $\lambda_i$s are nonnegative, the $\alpha$ defined in the proof is always nonnegative. Therefore, when $\mu_j$ is zero or negative, we will have $\lambda_j-\alpha\mu_j\ge\lambda_j\ge0$, i.e., the new $j$-th coefficient remains nonnegative.

When $\mu_j$ is positive, $\lambda_j-\alpha\mu_j$ will become smaller than $\lambda_j$. However, it is still nonnegative because $\alpha$ is defined as the minimiser among all ratios $\frac{\lambda_i}{\mu_i}$ over positive $\mu_i$s.

Therefore the new coefficients will all be nonnegative, regardless of the sign of each $\mu_j$. Since the coefficients sum up to $1$, the new linear combination is a convex one.

Comment: @ user1551,So essentially we are collecting all $j$s from the set $\{1,...,k\}$ whose $\mu_j$ is positive, and such $j$ exists, since the equation $$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \mu_j=0$$ Implies that the sum of all non-zero $\mu_j $s is equal to zero, and exists at least one such $j \in \{1,...,k\}$  whose $\mu_j$ is positive, otherwise the sum of all such $\mu_j$s cannot be zero, from here we see that $\alpha$ exists

Comment: @masaheb Yes. Alternatively, $\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_k$ by assumption are not all zero. If all nonzero members among them are negative, we can replace each $\mu_j$ (including $\mu_1$) by $-\mu_j$ to obtain a positive $\mu_j$.

Comment: @ user1551, 
Also the proof says "Suppose $k > d + 1$ (otherwise, there is nothing to prove)",I think if $k \le d+1$, then $x$ is already written as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points in $P$,right?

Comment: @masaheb Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @ user1551,

And the linear independence of  $\mathbf x_2 − \mathbf x_1, ..., \mathbf x_k − \mathbf x_1$ is because they belong to $\mathbb R^d$, so if we choose $m$ of them with $m > d$, then they cannot be linearly independent,is that correct?

Comment: @masaheb Hmm, what is $m$? Anyway, if you have more than $d$ vectors in a $d$-dimensional vector space, these vectors must be linearly dependent. This follows directly from the definition of vector space dimension that dimension = the maximal number of linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to write $x$ as a convex combination of $k-1$ points. So we have to modify the coefficients in the convex combination. We update $\lambda$ by a multiple of $\mu$. In order that the coefficients $\lambda_j - \alpha \mu_j$ stay non-negative one has
to choose $\alpha$ small.
Then $\sum_j (\lambda_j - \alpha \mu_j)x_j$ is again a convex combination of the $x_j$'s.
If $\alpha$ is chosen as written, then $\lambda_i - \alpha \mu_i=0$, and $x_i$ drops out of the convex combination.
This proves that $k-1$ vectors are sufficient.